# Rsync Issues with include/exclude command on MAC

Tags: macos, terminal, rsync, photo, file-management

I have folders & subfolders organized by date in the name containing files .jpg and .arw. I want to keep the same folder structure but move the JPG files to a copy of the folder structure AND delete them out of the source directory.

I was working on something like this that I could run in the terminal screen:

```
rsync -am --include="*/" --include=“*.jpg” --exclude=“*” /Users/adam/test\ 1/ /Users/Adam/test2/
```

But in my testing it's copying both the .jpg and .arw file to test2. Why is it moving the ARW file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your actual command have fancy ("smart") quotes around some of the patterns, like it does above? If so, that will mess them up; use only plain ASCII quotes on the command line.

Comment: lol I just manually typed it and got the expected result. Thanks for your input. I thought I was going crazy. New to mac...need to find a good code editor that is not TextEdit.

Comment: As you said you were on Mac: I wrote Truck.app for exactly this sort of reason.  It has a filter panel which lets you enter filters in a (hopefully) more user friendly way, and certainly makes experimental iterations faster because it's a drag-and-drop GUI.  Check it out if you want: http://bonhardcomputing.com/truck/  You can specify 'localhost' as the server address to achieve local operations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect quotes used due to copy and paste.